# Inefficient code in finding largest combination in list lower than a certain number

Tags: python

I am attempting a Codewars question but get a time out error which suggests that my code is taking too long to execute and is inefficient. I honestly do not see how I can adjust my current code to make it faster but would like some help. The aim of the code is to find the combination of `k` elements in a list `ls` that results in the highest sum below `t`. My code is as follows:

```
def choose_best_sum(t, k, ls):
    from itertools import product
    lists = [(s, sum(s)) for s in product(ls, repeat=k)]
    highest_sum = 0
    res = None
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        if lists[i][1]<t and lists[i][1]>highest_sum:
            highest_sum = lists[i][1]
            res = lists[i][0]
    return res
```

For example, `choose_best_sum(174, 3, [50, 55, 57, 58, 60])` should return (55,58,60)

Comment: This is a Knapsack problem, there are plenty of available algorithms for you to implement.  If your code works but you need to speed it up/improve it in other ways, this might be more appropriate for code review.

Comment: To clarify, yes - this could use some optimization (code review site - use the iterator it gives you), but it is the brute force knapsack solution, and therefore will fail horribly on a larger dataset regardless.

Comment: Use combinations instead of product, I just solved this challenge right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more performant version:

```
import timeit

def find_best_sum(threshold, k, ls):
    from itertools import combinations
    highest_sum = 0
    res = None
    for t in combinations(ls, r=k):
        s = sum(t)
        if s < threshold and s > highest_sum:
            highest_sum = s
            res = t
    return res


print(find_best_sum(174, 3, [50, 55, 57, 58, 60]))   # (55, 58, 60)
```

---

Comparison:

```
print('choose_best_sum', timeit.timeit('choose_best_sum(174, 3, [50, 55, 57, 58, 60])',
                    setup='from __main__ import choose_best_sum', number=1000))

print('find_best_sum', timeit.timeit('find_best_sum(174, 3, [50, 55, 57, 58, 60])',
                    setup='from __main__ import find_best_sum', number=1000))
```

Output (consecutively):

```
choose_best_sum 0.053198210999999995
find_best_sum 0.004936765999999981
```